# Removing everything except a "part" of the string

Tags: regex, sorting, notepad++

Here is the string, a full example:

```
('1416851040', '1416851040', '50.62.177.118', '84.161.97.189', 'humpy_electro', 393883, '385962628'),
('1416851046', '1416851046', '2607:5300:60:6097::', '80.187.100.105', 'lagbugdc', 393884, '737537953'),
('1416851067', '1416851067', '174.66.174.101', '98.148.244.151', 'maihym', 393885, '1473193487'),
('1416851094', '1416851094', '2607:5300:60:6097::', '92.157.2.230', 'xeosse26', 393886, '737537953'),
```

I'd like to remove -EVERYTHING- from it except: `facebook:jens.pettersson.7568`

(the username slot)
And where `facebook:jens.pettersson.7568` is actually `'facebook:jens.pettersson.7568'`, I'd like it to appear as:

`facebook:jens.pettersson.7568` (see the white space there?)

Then sort my list where all 361k lines line up like so:

x x xx xcx xzx xyx xtz

All with spaces, in technically 1 line, if possible.

Or if removing and just collecting the 1 line I need would suffice, I could manually do the sorting i suppose

Comment: `(see the white space there?)` I don't see any difference except the quotes removed.

Comment: The first try gave me this: 






', 'navi01232', 393893, '1473193487'),

Comment: It deleted all the rows except the last one, and left me with empty lines, and, that was the only data on the last line.

Comment: I still don't see the whitespace.

Comment: Unclear what you mean. What `'facebook:jens.pettersson.7568'` are you talking about ?

Comment: Given the fact that `facebook:jens.pettersson.7568` does not seem to appear even in part in any place in the input string (i.e. there's not even a `facebook` or a `jens` or a `petterson` or a `7568` in there), I would suggest either clarifying your example, or just ignoring the input altogether and going with `echo facebook:jens.pettersson.7568`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to read between the lines and guess that what you want is this:

```
BEFORE:
('1416851040', '1416851040', '50.62.177.118', '84.161.97.189', 'humpy_electro', 393883, '385962628'),
                                                                ^ this is username
AFTER:
facebook:humpy_electro
```

You could handle that with the following regex:

```
s/(?:[^,]*,){4}[\s'"]*([^'",]*).*/facebook:$1, /
```

i.e.

```
(?:                           # begin non-capturing group
    [^,]*,                    # zero or more non-comma characters, followed by a comma
){4}                          # end non-capturing group, and repeat 4 times
                              #   this skips the first 4 columns of data
[\s'"]*                       # matches any whitespace and the first quote
(                             # begin capturing group 1
    [^'",]*                   # capture all non-comma characters until the end quote
)                             # end capturing group 1
.*                            # match rest of line

# REPLACE WITH

facebook:                     # literal text
$1                            # capturing group 1
,                             # comma and a trailing space (not shown here)
```

And voila.

This turns this:

```
('1416851040', '1416851040', '50.62.177.118', '84.161.97.189', 'humpy_electro', 393883, '385962628'),
('1416851046', '1416851046', '2607:5300:60:6097::', '80.187.100.105', 'lagbugdc', 393884, '737537953'),
('1416851067', '1416851067', '174.66.174.101', '98.148.244.151', 'maihym', 393885, '1473193487'),
('1416851094', '1416851094', '2607:5300:60:6097::', '92.157.2.230', 'xeosse26', 393886, '737537953'),
```

Into this

```
facebook:humpy_electro, facebook:lagbugdc, facebook:maihym, facebook:xeosse26,
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it, from a friend, to do this was a 2 part: First step: ^((.*? '){4}) replace with nothing, then, second step '((.*?$){1}) replace with nothing.